# How to insert binary data using FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I am using FluentMigrator to manage a database.  One of the columns is of type `VARBINARY(MAX)` and I need to insert data into this column as part of a migration.

I have tried the following:

```
Insert.IntoTable("MyTable")
    .Row(new {
        MyColumn = new [] { 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C }
    });
```

However this does not seem to be correct (on account of the exceptions it throws).

Could someone point me in the right direction? (Database is SQL 2012, in case it makes a difference).

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question? I'm also need to get this to work.